# How to convert a NodeJS project written in JS to TS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, syntax, file-conversion

I am trying to convert a NodeJS project written in JS to TS. But I have problem with this file and gives me a lot of errors:

```
import express, {Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

const whitelist = ['http://localhost:3000' , 'https://localhost:3443', 'http://localhost:4200','http://localhost:5000'];

const corsOptionsDelegate  =(req, callback) => {
    let corsOptions;
    console.log('origin' + req.header('Origin'));
    if(whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1){
        console.log("index : " + whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')));
        corsOptions = { origin : true};
    }
    else{
        console.log('here else :' + whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')));
        corsOptions = { origin : false };
    }
    callback(null , corsOptions);
};

exports.cors = cors();
exports.corsWithOptions = cors(corsOptionsDelegate);
```

It needs type to be specified for `callback` function at this line:

```
const corsOptionsDelegate  =(req, callback) => {
```

Furthermore I don't know what to do with these two lines:

```
exports.cors = cors();
exports.corsWithOptions = cors(corsOptionsDelegate);
```

Comment: `const corsOptions` => `let corsOptions` - the main clue was the error message - if you're using ESM module syntax (which `import` suggests you are), then you `export something` not `export.something =` .... not sure how this is to do with conversion from js to ts though

Comment: The question is not clear. There is nothing to convert for the `exports` lines when it comes to TypeScript - maybe you instead ask how to convert these CommonJS exports to ESM? In that case the question should be updated. (And the solution would be `const corsInstance = cors(); export { corsInstance as cors }; export const corsWithOptions = cors(corsOptionsDelegate)`. The reason the first export is more complicated is only because you have a naming conflict with your variable `cors`.)

Answer (score -2):

you can resign a value to a const in javascript change const corsOptions; to var corsOptions;

check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_const.asp#:%7E:text=Variables%20defined%20with%20const%20cannot%20be%20Reassigned.)

you where reassigning in the if statement

Comment: Actually that was the simplest one that VSCode also suggests. Please go through the other errors and modifications.

Comment: There is no good reason to use `var` in 2022. Should be `let`.